# Code::blocks 16.01 not compiling

Tags: compiling, g++

I have Ubuntu 17.10 and Code::Blocks 16.01. I cannot build and run simple code like "Hello World!".

```
-------------- Build: Debug in program (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c /home/v4m3r/Documents/codeblocks/program/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
/bin/sh: 1: g++.exe: not found
Process terminated with status 127 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

I installed build-essential.

Comment: What command you are using to compile your code?

Answer (score 2):

Your compile command is `g++.exe` but `.exe` typically means a Windows executable. On Linux the command is `g++`. You should check your configuration and remove `.exe` from the command.